# How to remove all non-integer values in python

Tags: python, string, replace

Say I have "123asdf". How do I remove all non-integer characters so that it becomes "123"?

Comment: You missed this ?? `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249388/how-do-we-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-python`

Comment: What about characters like #@$ etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
''.join(x for x in your_string if x.isdecimal())
```

This takes those characters which are digits and adds them to a string.

### Examples

```
>>> your_string = 'asd8asdf798fad'
>>> print ''.join(x for x in your_string if x.isdecimal())
8798

>>> '1'.isdecimal()
True

>>> 'a'.isdecimal()
False
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this method:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\D", "", "123asdf")
'123'
```

Comment: Best method out of all the ones I've found, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, you can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), like this

```
data = "123asdf"
import string
print data.translate(None, string.letters)
# 123
```

Here, the first parameter to `str.translate` will be mapping of characters saying which character should be changed to what. The second parameter is the string of characters which need to be removed from the string. Since, we don't need to translate but remove alphabets, we pass `None` to the first parameter and `string.letters` to the second parameter.

In Python 3.x, you can do

```
import string
print(data.translate(data.maketrans("", "", string.ascii_letters)))
# 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '123asdf'
>>> filter(str.isdigit, s)
'123'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()) # alternate method
'123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex replacement:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("[^0-9]", "", "sdkjh987978asd098as0980a98sd")
'987978098098098'
```

Credits: [Removing all non-numeric characters from string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249388/how-do-we-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-python#answer-1249424)