# How to cast a int from string that contains not only numbers

Tags: python

Casting a string is easy:

```
string1 = "12"
int1 = int(string1)
```

But what if I want to extract the int from

```
string1 = "12 pieces"
```

The cast should return 12. Is there a pythonic way to do that and ignore any chars that are not numbers?

Comment: You need to extract the number from the string

Comment: Relevant: [Removing all non-numeric characters from string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249388/removing-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-python).

Comment: I thing I just answered it myself: `[int(s) for s in string1.split() if s.isdigit()]`

Comment: you can use `regex` or maybe you can split and do `try: int()` individually.

Comment: BTW: I would not really call this *casting*. This is simply calling the `int` constructor with a `str` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> string1 = "12 pieces"
>>> y = int(''.join([x for x in string1 if x in '1234567890']))
>>> print(y)
12
```

or better yet:

```
>>> string1 = "12 pieces"
>>> y = int(''.join([x for x in string1 if x.isdigit() ]))
>>> print(y)
12
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do that and ignore any chars that are not numbers?

Ignoring anything but a digit is, probably, not a good idea. What if a string contains `"12 pieces 42"`, should it return `12`, `1242`, `[12, 42]`, or raise an exception?

You may, instead, split the string and convert the first element to an `int`:

```
In [1]: int('12 pieces'.split()[0])
Out[1]: 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first part of the string is a number, one way to do this is to use a regex match:

```
import re

def strint(str):
    m=re.match("^[0-9]+", str)
    if m:
        return int(m.group(0))
    else:
        raise Exception("String does not start with a number")
```

The advantage of this approach is that even strings with just numbers can be cast easily, so you can use this function as a drop in replacement to `int()`