# How do I sum up values from a text file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I know there are a couple of post about this question on S.O. but they have not helped me solve my problem. I am trying to use an accumulator to sum up the values in a text file. When there is a number on each line my code just prints each line that is in the file. When there is a blank space between I get an error message. I think it is a simple oversight but I am new to Python so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
def main():
    #Open a file named numbers.txt
    numbers_file = open('numbers.txt','r')
    #read the numbers on the file
    number = numbers_file.readline()

    while number != '':
        #convert to integer
        int_number = int(number)
        #create accumulator
        total = 0
        #Accumulates a total number
        total += int_number
        #read the numbers on the file
        number = numbers_file.readline()
        #Print the data that was inside the file
        print(total)
    #Close the the numbers file
    numbers_file.close()

#Call the main function
main()
```

Inputs in the text file:

```
100

200

300

400

500

Gives me error message:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Inputs in the text file:

```
100
200
300
400
500

Prints:
100
200
300
400
500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude empty lines because you can't convert them to an `int()`. One pythonic (EAFP) way to do this is to catch the exception and ignore (though this will silently ignore any non-number line):

```
with open('numbers.txt','r') as numbers_file:
    total = 0
    for line in numbers_file:
        try:
            total += int(line)
        except ValueError:
            pass
print(total)
```

Or you can explicitly test that you don't have an empty string after you `.strip()` all the whitespace (this would still error for a non-numeric line, e.g. `'hello'`):

```
with open('numbers.txt','r') as numbers_file:
    total = 0
    for line in numbers_file:
        if line.strip():
            total += int(line)
print(total)
```

This second one can be written as a generator expression:

```
with open('numbers.txt','r') as numbers_file:
    total = sum(int(line) for line in numbers_file if line.strip())
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value `0` to your accumulator each time you go through the loop, before you add the new value. This means you're adding the new value to `0` each time, which means you're just printing the new value.
If you move the line `total = 0` to occur before the loop, then it should work as you were hoping.

If you want, you can clean this up a little:

```
numbers_file = open('numbers.txt','r')    
total = 0
for number in numbers_file:
    if number:  
        int_number = int(number)
        total += int_number
        print(total)
numbers_file.close()
```

would be a first pass. The check `if number` returns True if `number` contains a "truthy" value, which in this case would happen if you hit an empty line.

Comment: `number` will not be empty as it will still contain a newline `\n` on a empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are missing to remove the 'new line symbol' which is `\n`.
To ensure you get only literals that can be converted to numbers you have to strip other characters.
With e.g.

```
a = '100\ntest'
print(a.isnumeric())
a = '103478'
print(a.isnumeric())
```

You can test if there is a character that prevents conversion to a number.
The regular expression package to manipulate string easily.

See [this stack overflow threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249388/removing-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-python).

```
import re
a = jkfads1000ki'
re.sub('\D','',a)
'1000'
```

See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) on `re`.