# adding the numbers i read from a file

Tags: python

i want to add ints that is stored in a file and add the numbers to find the total.. i took this code from a txt book but im getting the following error :

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 12 4 55'

how can i solve this if i want to read the numbers one by 1 not by using a list

```
f = open("intgers.txt", 'r')
theSum = 0
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    number = int(line)
    theSum += number
print("The sum is", theSum)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732403/how-do-i-sum-up-values-from-a-text-file-in-python

Comment: how does your integers.txt look like ?

Comment: From what you show, you have multiple integers on one single line. You need to use `split` to separate each numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the line.

```py
f = open("intgers.txt", 'r')
theSum = 0
for line in f:
    numbers = line.strip().split(' ')
    for number in numbers:
        n = int(number)
        theSum += n
print("The sum is", theSum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code block, you're assuming each of the numbers are separated by new lines in `intgers.txt`. As the error suggests, the `line` variable is '1 2 3 12 4 55'. You can't convert that to an integer. You need to parse this into a list of numbers first:

```py
f = open("intgers.txt", 'r')
theSum = 0
for line in f:
    numbers = line.split()
    for num in numbers:
        number = int(num.strip())
        theSum += number
print("The sum is", theSum)
```

Look into uses of string methods [strip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) and [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) if you're confused.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are multiple space-separate integers on each line. You need to `.split()` each line and iterate over the resulting list to add the numbers from that line.

```py
f = open("intgers.txt", 'r')
theSum = 0
for line in f:
    splitline = line.strip().split()
    for item in splitline:
        number = int(item)
        theSum += number
print("The sum is", theSum)
```

There are a number of improvements that can be made to this, using `map` to apply the `int` function across the list and using implicit iteration to get a sum directly from each line. For interest:

```py
f = open("intgers.txt", 'r')
theSum = 0
for line in f:
    theSum += sum(map(int, line.strip().split()))
print("The sum is", theSum)
```