# Exclude the middle of a capture group regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
2km739
```

and I am trying to use a regex to capture the `2739`

I know I could just use two capture groups and combine them after (EDIT: or extract the numerical chars after I capture the group), but this would be a little easier in this situation and I am curious if this is possible.

I have this:

```
([0-9](?=[km])(?<=[km])\d+)
```

but it doesn't work

it only works if I add the `km` in there somewhere

```
([0-9](?=[km])km(?<=[km])\d+)
```

I would also think this would work, but I learned non-capture groups still get capture but the outside group

```
([0-9](?:km)\d+)
```

Comment: Can't you just [remove all non-numeric chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249388/removing-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-python)?

Comment: You can't have holes in capture groups.

Comment: @Wiktor I need the regex to find the 2km739, but you are right. I can do that afterward

Comment: Do you need to use regex?  Are you just trying to capture the numbers in the sequence they appear?  If so you can `''.join([x for x in list('2km739') if x.isnumeric()])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you regex you use `[km]` which is the notation for a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and will match `k` or `m`.

Maybe it is an option to capture the groups in a positive lookahead and then  join them:

[`^(?=(\d)km(\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/4JkP1n/1/)

```
str = "2km739"
reobj = re.compile(r"^(?=(\d)km(\d+))")
match = reobj.search(str)
print ''.join(match.groups())
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SFBL67381)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all of the letters and capture only digits, you can change the capture group to do that.

`(\d+)`

You'll need to merge all of the captured groups at the end, as you can't skip over pieces of the input without closing the capture group.