# python converting strings into three blocks and if not two blocks

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want to write a function that converts the given string T and group them into three blocks.
However, I want to split the last block into two if it can't be broken down to three numbers.
For example, this is my code

```
import re

def num_format(T):
    clean_number = re.sub('[^0-9]+', '', T)
    formatted_number = re.sub(r"(\d{3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d{3}))", r"\1-", clean_number) 
    return formatted_number


num_format("05553--70002654")
```

this returns : '055-537-000-2654' as a result.
However, I want it to be '055-537-000-26-54'.
I used the regular expression, but have no idea how to split the last remaining numbers into two blocks!

I would really appreciate helping me to figure this problem out!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
def num_format(T):
    clean_number = ''.join(c for c in T if c.isdigit())
    return re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?=\d{2})|(?<=\d{2})(?=\d{2}$)', r'\1-', clean_number)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l33XRV/1/).

Note you can get rid of all non-numeric chars using plain Python comprehension, the solution is borrowed from [Removing all non-numeric characters from string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249398/3832970).

The regex matches

- `(\d{3})` - Group 1 (`\1`): three digits...
- `(?=\d{2})` - followed with two digits
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\d{2})(?=\d{2}$)` - a location between any two digit sequence and two digits that are at the end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/O6YX1L):

```py
import re
 
def num_format(T):
    clean_number = ''.join(c for c in T if c.isdigit())
    return re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?=\d{2})|(?<=\d{2})(?=\d{2}$)', r'\1-', clean_number)
 
print(num_format("05553--70002654"))
# => 055-537-000-26-54
```