# Read numbers from string into float

Tags: python

I need to convert some strings to float. Most of them are only numbers but some of them have letters too. The regular float() function throws an error.

```
a='56.78'
b='56.78 ab'

float(a) >> 56.78
float(b) >> ValueError: invalid literal for float()
```

One solution is to check for the presence of other characters than numbers, but I was wondering if there is some built-in or other short function which gives:

```
magicfloat(a) >> 56.78
magicfloat(b) >> 56.78
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip all non-numeric characters (except for ".") from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947776/strip-all-non-numeric-characters-except-for-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `regex`

```
import re

def magicfloat(input):
    numbers = re.findall(r"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", input)

    # TODO: Decide what to do if you got more then one number in your string
    if numbers:
        return float(numbers[0])

    return None

a=magicfloat('56.78')
b=magicfloat('56.78 ab')

print a
print b
```

output:

```
56.78
56.78
```

Comment: This would be the other solution that I would propose.

Answer (score 3):

You can try stripping letters from your input:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

b='56.78 ab'
float(b.strip(ascii_lowercase))
```

Comment: If you put in an input like `b='56.78 ab#$'`, this does not work.

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick, the question did say 'other letters', so the solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: No.

There is no built-in function that can accomplish this.

**Long*ish* answer**: Yes:

One thing you can do is go through each character in the string to check if it is a digit or a period and work with it from there:

```
def magicfloat(var):
    temp = list(var)
    temp = [char for char in temp if char.isdigit() or char == '.']
    var = "".join(temp)
    return var
```

As such:

```
>>> magicfloat('56.78 ab')
'56.78'
>>> magicfloat('56.78')
'56.78'
>>> magicfloat('56.78ashdusaid')
'56.78'
>>>
```