# Extract a number from a string in a list

Tags: python, list, numbers, extract

How can I extract the prices from a list that contains for example:

```
[<span class="primary-price">$61,989</span>,
 <span class="primary-price">$21,905</span>,
 <span class="primary-price">$20,595</span>]
```

It should give me back:
prices = [61.989,21.905,20.595] or at least
prices = [$61,989, $21,905, $20,595]

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use python...

Comment: What did you try? There are lots of questions here that ask how to extract a dollar amount from a string. Did you do any [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/843953) before asking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163913/extract-currency-amount-from-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expression (pattern matching)

```
import re

string = '''[<span class="primary-price">$61,989</span>,
 <span class="primary-price">$21,905</span>,
 <span class="primary-price">$20,595</span>]'''

numbers = re.findall('\$(\d+,\d+)', string)
```

You can also replace the comma(,) and convert it to integers

```
numbers = [int(num.replace(',', '')) for num in numbers ]
print(numbers)
```