# How to parse from a string the numbers and punctuation in Python

Tags: python

I want to turn a string like "$1,234.56" into 1234.56 so I can add it to a database, my current solution is using `re.sub("[^0-9]", "", str1` this however strips the punctuation too, is there a way to keep it?

I'm using python 3.6.5

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of a regex question, but going to answer it anyway.

Comment: if you know it will always be '$' and ',' that you will strip off, I think you can use re.sub("[$,]",'' str1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580151/parse-currency-into-numbers-in-python

Comment: I tried the "re.sub("[$,]",'' str1)" method, it gave me a Syntax Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", str1)`

will keep the decimal dot too. Is there any other punctuation you want to keep?

Note that this will still fail to produce a valid integer on inputs with **more than one decimal dot**, such as `123..45` or `1.2.3` or `.` or `1.` or anything that looks weird.

The code discards everything but numbers and points, with no regard as to how many points or numbers are there. An infeasible number such that `223523523948231472389523` will still be kept, and depending on the way your database works (whether or not it can store numbers above 64 bits), the resulting number stored in the database **may be negative or truncated**!