# Extract digits from currency symbol and format it

Tags: python, regex, currency

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Input             |    Excepted            |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| EUR 1.409,00      |    1409                |
| $ 409,05          |    409.05              |
| ￥409.50          |    409.5               |
| CNY 1,000         |    1000                |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

The first thought came into my mind is regular expression. I can't write it though.
How do you figure this out?

Comment: The first thought which came into my head is that you should be using a Python library which can convert numbers from one locale to the other.  The regex part of this is fairly trivial; you only need to extract the numbers from the text.

Comment: For example Babel? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37598997/8069403

Comment: I think you mean **currency** not **concurrency**. Currency is money, concurrency is doing multiple things at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several regex iterations:

```
import re

results = []

# Get list of numbers
numbers = re.findall('[\d,.]+', 'EUR 1.409,00 $ 409,05 ￥409.50 CNY 1,000.00')

# Parse number
for number in numbers:
    dp = ''
    ip = number
    match = re.search('(?<=[,.])(?:\d{2})$', number)
    # Get decimal places
    if match:
        dp = match.group()
        # Extract integer places
        ip = number[:match.start()]
    # Remove commas and periods from integer
    ip = ip.translate(None, ',.')
    # Parse float
    results.append(float('{}.{}'.format(ip, dp)))
print(results)
```

This results in `[1409.0, 409.05, 409.5, 1000.0]`.
I would bet there's a much more convenient regex to do this all in one, but at least it should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you can use the regex `([0-9.,]+)` to extract the numbers with varying decimal locales.

Then, you will likely want to follow Tim Biegeleisen's advice, and use a locale library to convert them into numbers.