# Getting Data from API and Parsing

Tags: python, api

For context, I'm really new to web-development.

Is there a better way of getting the data from [this website](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR) than removing non-numeric characters from the string you get from .read(), such as [shown in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947776/strip-all-non-numeric-characters-except-for-from-a-string-in-python) and then separating the two numbers?

If the python script is calling the API and getting data, how would you automate that process to refresh the data in a time period (e.g. every minute)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This data is in JSON format, you can retrieve it as a Python dict using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library:

```
>>> import requests
>>> data = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR"
                  ).json()
>>> data
{'BTC': 0.1432, 'EUR': 343.04, 'USD': 388.04}
```

If you want to run it regularly there are a few different options; you could use cron (or taskscheduler on windows), or you could use a loop with `time.sleep(60)`.

Answer (score 2):

That data is in JSON format, which is roughly equivalent to a dictionary in Python. I'm not an expert in Python, but I believe that you'll need to import the `json` module and parse the data with `.loads()` - then you can access the values as properties of the dictionary.

So for example, your data looks like this:

```
{"BTC":0.1434,"USD":387.92,"EUR":343.51}
```

In your script, you'll import `json`, put the data into a variable, and parse it as a dictionary:

```
import json

json_string = '{"BTC":0.1434,"USD":387.92,"EUR":343.51}'
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
```

Now if you reference `parsed_json`, you can access the values:

```
print parsed_json['BTC'] 
# 0.1434

print parsed_json['EUR']
# 343.51
```

And so on.

**Edit**
After re-reading your question, I feel like what you are aiming for is some combination of the accepted answer and mine. Here's what I think you're looking for (borrowing from the accepted answer):

```
>>> import requests

>>> data = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR"
              ).json()
>>> data['USD']
387.92
>>> data['BTC']
0.1434
```

The data returned by `requests.get()` is already parsed, so there's no need to parse it again with `json.loads()`. To access the value of a dictionary's attribute, type the name of the dictionary and then the attribute in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Python has the ability to parse json resposne from api into dictionary results
https://pythonspot.com/en/json-encoding-and-decoding-with-python/ gives a good tutorial on using json. To automate to run every minute take a look at [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python) . I hope this is helpful